# Get object from RecyclerView after clicking on it

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room

I'm very new to Room and RecyclerViews in general, and I'm trying to get the object I click on in order to pass it to another screen. I've been looking around, but everything I see is confusing, and by the end I get nothing. The most I know is that I have to get the position of the RecyclerView item in order to locate the object, how? This are the classes that are related to this procedure:

Activity:

```
package com.gmproxy.pastilarma;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gmproxy.Adapters.PathologyListAdapter;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.Pathology;
import com.gmproxy.Util.PathologyViewModel;

import java.io.File;

public class PathologiesSearchScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PathologyViewModel viewModel;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pathology_search_list);

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.SearchView);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        final PathologyListAdapter adapter = new PathologyListAdapter(new PathologyListAdapter.UserDiff());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PathologyViewModel.class);
        viewModel.pathologies.observe(this, adapter::submitList);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                viewModel.setFilter(searchView.getQuery().toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                long start;
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if ((newText.length() > 3) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > 500)){
                    viewModel.setFilter(searchView.getQuery().toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new RecyclerView.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.onBindViewHolder();
                Pathology path = new Pathology(,);
                final CharSequence[] options = {"Si","No"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PathologiesSearchScreen.this);
                builder.setTitle("¿Añadir la patología "+ path.getPathologyName() +"?");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (options[item].equals("Si")) {
                            Toast.makeText(PathologiesSearchScreen.this, "Has añadido la patología " + path.getPathologyName() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent mainAct = new Intent(PathologiesSearchScreen.this, UserAddScreen.class);
                            mainAct.putExtra("path", path);
                            startActivity(mainAct);
                            finish();
                        } else if (options[item].equals("No")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
package com.gmproxy.Util;

import android.app.Application;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations;

import com.gmproxy.DAO.PathologyRepository;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.Pathology;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PathologyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        private PathologyRepository repository;
        public LiveData<List<Pathology>> pathologies;
        public MutableLiveData<String> filteredList = new MutableLiveData<>();

        public PathologyViewModel(Application application) {
                super(application);
                repository = new PathologyRepository(application);
                pathologies = Transformations.switchMap(filteredList, (input) -> {
                        if(input == null || input.equals("")){
                                return repository.getAllObjects();
                        } else {
                                return repository.filter(input);
                        }
                });
        }

        public void setFilter(String query){
                filteredList.setValue(query);
        }

        LiveData<List<Pathology>> getAllPathologies() { return pathologies; }

        public void insert(Pathology obj) { repository.insertObject(obj); }


}
```

ViewHolder:

```
package com.gmproxy.Adapters;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.gmproxy.pastilarma.R;

class PathologyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView objItemView;

    private PathologyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        objItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void bind(String text) {
        objItemView.setText(text);
    }

    static PathologyViewHolder create(ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pathologies_item, parent, false);
        return new PathologyViewHolder(view);
    }



}
```

ListAdapter:

```
package com.gmproxy.Adapters;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter;

import com.gmproxy.Entities.Pathology;


public class PathologyListAdapter extends ListAdapter<Pathology, PathologyViewHolder> {

    public PathologyListAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Pathology> diffCallback) {
        super(diffCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public PathologyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return PathologyViewHolder.create(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PathologyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pathology current = getItem(position);
        holder.bind(current.getPathologyName());
    }

    public static class UserDiff extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Pathology> {

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Pathology oldItem, @NonNull Pathology newItem) {
            return oldItem == newItem;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Pathology oldItem, @NonNull Pathology newItem) {
            return oldItem.getPathologyName().equals(newItem.getPathologyName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the bind method in `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter. Here you get the current `Pathology` object instance which is being inflated. You can set an `OnClickListener` here or in the `bind` method you are calling. Suppose you want your `objItemView` to be clicked. One way is inside the `bind` method.

```
public void bind(String text) {
    objItemView.setText(text);
    objItemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // your task here
    });
}
```

Another way is inside `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PathologyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Pathology current = getItem(position);
    holder.objItemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // your task here
    });
    holder.bind(current.getPathologyName());
}
```

But in this case you have to make your `objItemView` public.

Comment: Meaning that if I wanted to get the object, I could create a custom query which gives me the object where the String text = the pathology name like this? How would I then get this object to use it? https://i.gyazo.com/01d384d6a13228ad12f3e270d81c79da.png

Comment: Besides, this doesn't quite address the problem that I still need to get the position of the item inside the recyclerview

Comment: `Pathology current = getItem(position);` here `current` is your object.

Comment: You can use `current` as per your requirement.